# Prove that $S^n$ is $(n-1)$-connected.

Tags: algebraic-topology, higher-homotopy-groups

I heard someone mention that since $S^n$ is $(n-1)$-connected (i.e. $\pi_k (S^n) = 0$ for $k<n$), $\pi_2 (S^3)=0$. However, I can't seem to imagine how this is the case. The person who said it made it seem trivial, so I've come to the conclusion that this is probably a stupid question, but are there any easy/intuitive ways to understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that any map $S^n\to S^{n+k}$ is nullhomotopic for any $k\geq 1$. Give $S^n$ and $S^{n-k}$ the a CW structure consisting of only one $0$-cell and one $n$-cell (or $n-k$ cell respectfully). Use cellular approximation to obtain a cellular map $S^n\to S^{n+k}$. By definition, for any CW complex $X$, we have $X^{k-1}\subset X^k$, so by definition of cellular maps the image $S^n$ must be contained in the $n$-skeleton of $S^{n+k}$. But this is just a point (namely the $0$-skeleton of $S^{n+k}$).

The proof can also be cast in terms of Whitney's approximation and Sard's theorem (as the other answers indicated).

Answer (score 3):

Continuous maps are homotopic to smooth maps. Smooth maps $S^k \to S^n$, for $k<n$, are for dimensional reasons not surjective due to Sard's theorem. By removing a point from $S^n$ you get $\mathbb{R}^n$, and thus such maps are homotopic to a constant.

Comment: Do you mind being a tiny bit more explicit about how Sard's theorem is used here?

Comment: @Beepo Since $n>k$, the whole image consists of critical values. Sard's theorem says that the set of critical values has measure zero, so in particular it is not everything.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How does removing a point get you $R^n$ though?

Comment: @Beepo $S^n \backslash \{p\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Perhaps the most common way to prove this is by using a [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#Generalizations).

Comment: Where are you nowadays, @AloizioMacedo? I voted for you as moderator all those years ago, so I was surprised to see you contribute after a long time, and that too on the main site!  I hope you come more frequently, the main and meta sites need your participation!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Hi! I've been somewhat distant for the past few months. I am in the last months of my making my dissertation (I'll probably defend it in May or June) and I've had a health problem in my close family that has thrown me off a bit. I check in to see how things are going but do not interact much. I expect to be back to activity soon, and sorry for the abscence. I hope everything is well with you.

Comment: Yes, I am doing well! I hope you are back in activity soon, all I wanted to inform you was that we are waiting for you to come back, and it was nice seeing you contribute after a long time. I hope the health problem does not cause you much distress, and I hope you emerge from it with flying colours. We are here for you, helping moderate the site in your absence, until you come back!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I am aware of for proving this is the F[reudenthal suspension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudenthal_suspension_theorem), which is not very hard.

Answer (score 0):

The argument goes that when $0\lt i\lt n $, any continuous map from $S^i $ to $S^n $ is homotopy equivalent to a non-surjective map.  Then since $S^n\setminus\{\text {pt}\}\cong\mathbb R^n $ is contractible,  the map is homtopically trivial.

To make the first part rigorous,  see the *cellular approximation theorem*.  This is somewhat difficult because of the existence of space-filling curves.  When $i=1$ and $n=2$, there's the intuition that a rubber band wrapped around a sphere can be deformed to a point.

Comment: Why is any map $S^i\to S^n$ homotopy equivalent to a non-surjective map?

Comment: it is homotopy equivalent to a constant map by the cellular approximation theorem :). This is really a general topology result (imo) there are several proofs. If you put some background in the main question im sure that someone can offer a proof/reference to your taste